# Is there a standard class / type that represents valid Python identifiers?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Being interpreted and lassez-faire, Python often blurs the boundary between what's an entity in the language (like a variable or class) or simply an entry in a runtime dictionary. The perhaps most prominent example are keyword arguments: one can switch between calling a function with individual arguments, whose names are Python identifiers, or with a single dict, whose keys are strings:

```
In [1]: def viking(spam, eggs):
   ...:     print(f"Eating {spam}")
   ...:     print(f"Eating {eggs}")
   ...:     print(f"Eating more {spam}")
   ...: 

In [2]: viking(spam="spammedy", eggs="eggedy")
Eating spammedy
Eating eggedy
Eating more spammedy

In [3]: viking(**{"spam": "spammedy", "eggs": "eggedy"})
Eating spammedy
Eating eggedy
Eating more spammedy
```

Both styles aren't equi-general though: while `spam` and `eggs` are valid identifiers, a string like `"5+a.@))"` does not correspond to something that could actually be a Python variable name.

As [discussed elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534634/attributes-which-arent-valid-python-identifiers), Python itself makes a point of *not* preventing an attribute to be set as something that wouldn't be a legal identifier, but assume I wish to write some macro code that does enforce this. Is there somewhere in the standard libraries a class whose values correspond precisely to legal identifiers? Or at least a function that can be called to check whether or not a string represents such an identifier?

After all, these sort of considerations matter – if not elsewhere then at least when it comes to *parsing Python code* from plain text.

It turns out rather tricky to search the internet for something like that!

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/12700893/3001761? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isidentifier

Comment: No, I somehow missed those in my search. That answers the B-plan. I suppose for the A-plan of a class that encapsulates this, the answer is _no_ then?

Comment: The default implementation of `object.__setattr__` allows the attribute name to be an arbitrary string. You can override this method to perform some validation of the name being assigned, if that's what you are asking about.

Comment: The definition of "identifier" is [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). As Python itself doesn't have any macro-definition facilities, it's not clear what else, exactly, you are looking for that excludes `str.isidentifier`.

Comment: @chepner I'm looking for a type which is an abstraction over the concept of Python identifiers, i.e. a class whose instances (assuming no interface abuse) are in 1-to-1 relationship with the set of strings that would be legal if used as a Python variable name.

Comment: OK, no, there is no subtype of `str` that corresponds to valid identifiers :)

Comment: @leftaroundabout there is no such type. the set of valid identifiers is enormous, by the way.